# Passing object to method in NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

This is a really dumb question. How would you pass an object to a method using an NSTimer?
I mean something like this -

I have a method in `BigView.m` that has a method called `doSomethingWithClass:`.

```
- (void)doSomethingWithClass:(CustomClass *)class {
    NSLog(@"Something was done");
}
```

In another class called `CustomClass`, I have an NSTimer -

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:bigView selector:@selector(doSomethingWithClass:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Where bigView is an instance of BigView. Now I want to pass an entire instance of CustomClass as the parameter in the method `doSomethingWithClass:`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to refer to the timer, use the simpler [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a).

```
[bigView performSelector:@selector(doSomethingWithClass:)
              withObject:customClass
              afterDelay:0.5];
```

(To cancel it, [use `+cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:…`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget%3aselector%3aobject%3a).)